# Run Multiple Jenkins Builds With Same Configurations

Tags: maven, jenkins

We have a couple hundred Maven projects running on our Jenkins servers, all of them with slightly different arguments and goals.

Now we want to start quality control and so we want to enable some more goals for these projects (like `sonar:sonar` or `clirr:check`).

We can't really add these new goals to the existing projects, because of course we need the regular builds to return as quickly as possible for our developers to work.

But creating hundreds of new projects just for these goals is really tedious.

So I hope to find a way to run all these projects with a different set of parameters / goals / whatever.

I checked the [matrix projects](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project), but that's the opposite: running the same build with different configurations.

Is there any way to run multiple Jenkins projects again with the same set of arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, by making the builds parametrized. You can add several parameters to the build (string, file, ...)
Have a loook at this page: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build
If you want to run the same build with another goal, you can add a string parameter (then you can type, whatever goal you want to run) or you can provide choice of goals.
The parameter is then available as environment variable, which you can refer in your maven call.

Comment: Can I add these parameters for multiple projects at once? And is there a way to have automatic builds with and without the parameters?

Comment: Adding thess parameters at once is (afaik) only possible via script. Automatic builds are still possible, you can add default values for the parameters, which are used, if you don't pass the values or you can explicitly pass the values via Jenkins-API